# pg_dump blocked by another transaction using TRANSACTION_REPEATABLE_READ

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, pg-dump

I have a java program exporting selected data from several tables of a Postgres database. The logic is

1. set the isolation level to TRANSACTION_REPEATABLE_READ
2. select data from table 1 and export them to an external file
3. select data from table 2 and export them
4. commit

While the program is running, if I run pg_dump to backup the database, pg_dump will be blocked until my program is finished.

I am using REPEATABLE_READ to make sure my export data is consistent, i.e. not affected by other concurrent transaction.  Any suggestion how to get a consistent set of data without blocking pg_dump?

Thanks

Comment: What version?  What arguments are given to pg_dump?

Comment: I am using version 9.2.21.  The pg_dump command that I used is

Comment: You didn't include anything for the command line.  It would be better to edit the question to add that info anyway.  I can't reproduce this based on your description, even on the ancient 9.2.

Comment: The backup command that I used is "pg_dumpall --clean --file=data.sql".  Thanks